# Flask WSGI subdomain dispatching causing 404s on app instances

Tags: python, flask

My goal is for my Flask app to switch databases based on the subdomain.

The [subdomain dispatcher described in the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appdispatch/#dispatch-by-subdomain) is useful and I'm using [something based off it](https://wsgisubdomain.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Everything seems to work fine but only 2 instances seem to work at a given time despite the SubDomainDispatcher having multiple instances loaded. The other instances give out 404s.

My **create_app** function is as follows:

```
def create_app(subdomain):
    app = Flask("proj", static_folder="../static", template_folder="../templates")


    with app.app_context():
        app.config.from_object('proj.config')

        app.config.update(
            SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://root:password@localhost:3306/' + subdomain + '_proj',
            HOST = subdomain + app.config["HOST"],
        )

        from proj.models import db, Models

        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql://root:passwordT@localhost:3306")
        engine.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS "+subdomain+"_proj")
        engine.execute("use "+subdomain+"_proj")

        db.init_app(app)
        db.create_all()

        mail = Mail(app)

        store = DictStore()
        KVSessionExtension(store, app)

        import proj.views

        return app
```

I'm using Apache with mod_wsgi:

**Apache Config**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mywebsite.com
        ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/proj/app.wsgi
        WSGIDaemonProcess application user=www-data group=www-data processes=5 threads=20

        <Directory /var/www/proj/proj/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        #Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
        #<Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
        #    Order allow,deny
        #    Allow from all
        #</Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**wsgi file**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/proj')

from subdomain import SubdomainDispatcher
from proj import create_app
application = SubdomainDispatcher(create_app)
```

Seems like some sort of race condition but I don't see where or why it would be happening. I've tried reducing the amount of processes and threads to 1 each but that also did not see to work.

Any advice is greatly appreciated as I've been struggling with this for awhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few other eyes took a look, the problem is that imports will only run once causing routes to only ever be associated to the first app created.

Essentially views are only ever instantiated once for the first app/subdomain hit.

The solution is instead of importing you have function in each module initializing the routes.

As so in **views.py**:

```
def init_views(app):
    @app.route('/page')
    def page():
        return "asdf"
```

Thus each app has it's own copy of the routes instead of only the first.

What a doozy.